# Syntax Error after adding knox to urls.py

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-knox

I am new to Django and django-rest-framework. I am building an API and I want to implement auth using Django-rest-Knox. I have added Knox to the installed apps in the settings.py. In the urls.py of the project, I added the path to Knox. It seems there is a syntax error.

```
urls.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path("api/", include('core.urls'))
    path("api/auth/", include('knox.urls')),

]
```

This is the error message :

path("api/auth/", include('knox.urls')),
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Missing comma on the previous line.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot a comma after `path("api/", include('core.urls'))`, so it runs into the next line. Try adding it and see if the error persists.

I hope this helps.